# R.4.0 installation on Linux Mint LMDE4

Tags: r, linux, linux-mint

I change from Windows recently. I'm trying to install **R 4.0** on **Linux Mint LMDE4**. The command 'apt install r-base r-base-dev' insall R 3.5. I try to follow some instructions inserting the 'deb' url package in the etc/apt/source.list and does not work. I updated by 'apt update', remove the previous r-base and r-base-dev and tried again. The public key provided by r-project does not work. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This might help https://community.rstudio.com/t/update-r-linux-mint/34402

Comment: Thank you! I found another solution

Comment: @AlfredoNeto could you pls put the solution here? I've the same problem. Tkx